# ListView remove only last items

Tags: android, android-listview

I have List view with custom adapter and I have problem with removing items from list. Here is definition of list row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/history_list_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/history_list_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/history_list_check"/>
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/history_list_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/history_drunk_image_description"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom adapter:

```
public class HistoryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Measure> {
    
private final List<HistoryRowModel> list;
private final Activity context;

public HistoryArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Measure> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.history_list_row, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = new ArrayList<HistoryRowModel>();
    
    for(Measure measure : list) {
        HistoryRowModel rowModel = new HistoryRowModel(measure);
        this.list.add(rowModel);
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
    protected TextView text;
    protected ImageView imageView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.history_list_row, null);
        
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.history_list_check);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                HistoryRowModel element = (HistoryRowModel) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });
        
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_list_label);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_list_image);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    
    HistoryRowModel rowModel = list.get(position);
    Measure measure = rowModel.getMeasure();
    long time = measure.getTimestamp();
    DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();
    holder.text.setText(dateFormat.format(time));
    
    int resource = getImage(measure.getThreshold());
    if(resource == -1)
    {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(resource);
    }
    
    return view;
}
}
```

And here is my remove from list code:

```
private void removeSelectedRows() {
    View v;
    CheckBox cb;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
        v = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.history_list_check);
        if(cb.isChecked())
        {
            removeMeasure(i);
        }
    }
}

private void removeMeasure(long rowId) {
    
    Measure toRemove = adapter.getItem((int)rowId);
    
    try {
        Dao<Measure, Integer> measureDao = databaseHelper.getMeasureDao();
        DeleteBuilder<Measure, Integer> db = measureDao.deleteBuilder();
        db.where().eq("id", toRemove.getId());
        measureDao.delete(db.prepare());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    adapter.remove(toRemove);
}
```

My problem is that when I check some item and then invoke removeSelectedRows its remove always last item from list. Then when I return from this activity and go back again it's turn out that the proper row was delete from database and list show proper list rows. So it's looks like line

```
adapter.remove(toRemove);
```

remove wrong item from adapter. Any idea what is wrong with this code?

### SOLVED

njzk2 was right in his comment

Comment: do you call notifydatasetchanged?

Comment: Are you sure that you're reffering to the right Adapter object? We don't see how you initialized "adapter" object here, but since you're calling it via list.getAdapter() method in the first place, why don't you use that in the removeMeasure() method as well?

Comment: it removes an item from the measure list, but you are displaying items from the historyrowmodel list. The count of items is the count of measures, hence the 1 item less is displayed, but since you don't touch the historyrowmodel list, it only appears to hide the last tem

Comment: @AYMADA Can you tell how u fix that issue in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all your `adapter` calls with `list.getAdapter()` calls. Or at least show us how you initialize the `adapter` variable.

EDIT: The notifyOnChange flag is 'true' by default so calling any of the following adapter methods will invoke the notifyDataSetChanged() method of the same object: `add(T), insert(T), remove(T), clear()`

Comment: njzk2 was right int his comment under my post. Ty for trying help :)